# Where is the information stored in the USB core regarding the class driver and the HCDs, for it to check?

Tags: drivers, usb, devices

Obvious by the question, does the USB core have an array or something (maybe a linked list) where all the class drivers' information and HCD's information (a name or some kinda number) is stored so that it checks and assign the required when a device is plugged in?

Comment: The core? Do you mean the kernel?

Comment: edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Linux kernel, the module loader is woken up when a new device is
detected. It's passed a "**modalias**" string, which identifies the device and
looks something like this for USB devices:

```
usb:v058Fp6387d0103dc00dsc00dp00ic08isc06ip50in00
```

You can find your device **modalias** (and the HCD driver) using the following command:

```
udevadm info --export-db
```

This is the section related to my USB drive:

```
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.0
E: DEVTYPE=usb_interface
E: DRIVER=usb-storage
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=Flash Drive
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Alcor Micro Corp.
E: INTERFACE=8/6/80
E: MODALIAS=usb:v058Fp6387d0103dc00dsc00dp00ic08isc06ip50in00
E: PRODUCT=58f/6387/103
E: SUBSYSTEM=usb
E: TYPE=0/0/0
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=530904794
```

This string contains the device class (usb) and class-specific information
(vendor/product/serial number, device class, etc). Each kernel driver
contains a line such as:

```
MODULE_ALIAS("usb:...")
```

Which must match the usbalias (wildcards are used to match multiple
devices). If the modalias matches one that the driver supports, this driver
is loaded (or notified of the new device, if it's there already).

You can see the supported devices (by modalias) and their associated modules with

```
more /lib/modules/`uname -r`/modules.alias
```

If you grep for the usb-storage device driver, you'll see it has some
specific devices it supports by vendor and device ID, and will also attempt
to support any device with the right (storage) class, no matter the
vendor/device.

The USB modalias can be decoded like this:

```
usb:
v   vendor_id (4 hex)
p   product_id (4 hex)
d   revision (4 hex)
dc  class (2 hex)
dsc subclass (2 hex)
dp  protocol (2 hex)
ic  interface_class (2 hex)
isc interface_subclass (2 hex)
ip  interface_protocol (2 hex)
```

<sub>[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26132/how-to-assign-usb-driver-to-device)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[lsusb](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/lsusb.8.html)

FILES

```
   /var/lib/usbutils/usb.ids
          A  list  of  all  known  USB  ID’s  (vendors, products, classes,
          subclasses and protocols).
```

That file is only present if there are USB devices.

- [Here is the full on-line list](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids).

Comment: I dint mean that. I meant the info regarding the Class drivers, and the HCDs which core accesses when a device is plugged in. Someone said that there must be some kinda array or linked list or something.